# Python tuple inside list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a data structure like below, How do I append new values based on the name. Like, if input name is Sam and amount is 200. if Sam already existed, it should append to Sam's list otherwise it should create a new element in the list.

```
data = [('Sam',[100,120,110]),('Andrew',[80,90,100]),('Gram',[400,300,350]),
              ('Jeremy',[125, 100]), ('Mike',[75,30])]
```

Comment: Take a look at python dictionaries [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries). It will help you to create a better data structure, which will in turn allow you to perform indexing (by name itself). This will make your insertion and lookup task much more easier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use dictionary, asked in the interview today and have no clue :)

Comment: split problem to smaller problem - first find `Sam` and later try to do something whit this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Iterating over list of tuples and replace / add tuple

As a basic rule, tuples are non-mutable. So you cannot change a tuple. However, you can replace a tuple with another tuple inside a list. That's how we are going to solve your problem.

Here's the code to do this.

```
data = [('Sam',[100,120,110]),('Andrew',[80,90,100]),('Gram',[400,300,350]),
              ('Jeremy',[125, 100]), ('Mike',[75,30])]

name = input ('Enter name to add to list : ')
while True:
    try:
        value = int (input ('Enter value to add to list : '))
        break
    except:
        print ('not a number')

for i,(nm,vals) in enumerate(data):
    if nm == name:
        vals +=[value]
        data[i] = (nm,vals)
        break
else:
    data.append ((name,[value]))

print (data)
```

The output is as follows:
Example with a name that exists in the list:

```
Enter name to add to list : Sam
Enter value to add to list : 250
[('Sam', [100, 120, 110, 250]), ('Andrew', [80, 90, 100]), ('Gram', [400, 300, 350]), ('Jeremy', [125, 100]), ('Mike', [75, 30])]
```

Another example with a name that does not exist in the list:

```
Enter name to add to list : Joe
Enter value to add to list : 250
[('Sam', [100, 120, 110]), ('Andrew', [80, 90, 100]), ('Gram', [400, 300, 350]), ('Jeremy', [125, 100]), ('Mike', [75, 30]), ('Joe', [250])]
```

## Using Dictionary instead of tuples

If you are interested in an alternate approach, you can convert the list of tuples into a dictionary. Then insert the data into a dictionary, and convert it back to a list of tuple.

```
#convert the list of tuples to a dict of lists 
data_dict = {nm:vals for nm,vals in data}

#use setdefault to add the value. append() allows you to append if key exists
data_dict.setdefault(name,[]).append(value)

#convert it back to a list of tuples
data_list = [(nm,vals) for nm,vals in data_dict.items()]

print (data_list)
```

Same results as above.

Answer (score 1):

To start with a python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) would be much more fitting for what you are trying to do. But I am guessing you either have a reason you can't use that or you want to learn how to iterate through a list.

Here is the example code:

```
data = [('Sam',[100,120,110]),('Andrew',[80,90,100]),('Gram',[400,300,350]),
              ('Jeremy',[125, 100]), ('Mike',[75,30])]


## Create a function so you can call this elsewhere
def append_value(name, value):

    ## Iterate over the list
    for each in data:

        ## If the passed name equals a name in your list do something
        if each[0] == name:

            ## Append the value to the list in the tuple
            each[1].append(value)
            
            ## Use return to break the for loop
            ## Return true if a value was added
            return True

    ## If no name in the list equaled the passed name we get here
    ## Return false so we know that something went wrong
    return False

## Print data before addition
## Output: [('Sam', [100, 120, 110]), ('Andrew', [80, 90, 100]), ('Gram', [400, 300, 350]), ('Jeremy', [125, 100]), ('Mike', [75, 30])]
print(data)

## Append new number to "sam" and print the return
## Output: True
print(append_value('Sam', 400))

## Print data after addition
## Output: [('Sam', [100, 120, 110, 400]), ('Andrew', [80, 90, 100]), ('Gram', [400, 300, 350]), ('Jeremy', [125, 100]), ('Mike', [75, 30])]
print(data)
```

I commented each line so you know what it does as well as give the outputs to the prints. Without using a dict you have to iterate through the entire list by hand. Please let me know if this helps or if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is much better for your purpose.

```
data.setdefault(name, []).append(value)
```

If you insist on using the existing list of tuples, then iterate on all items and read the name at zero index of tuple and proceed accordingly. Ugly and inefficient.

```
for items in data:
    if item[0] == name:
        name_found = True
        item[1].append(value)
if not name_found:
    data.append((name,[value]))
name_found = False
```

Answer (score 1):

While simple iteration can solve the problem. But if you are curious and speed is a crucial thing and moreover can't use `dict` then you can look up how `dict` or `hash map` work. You can implement the same.

Here I am giving one example, but it does not balance itself, meaning that if the data structure is full, you need to expand the list `index` to suppose 2 times. But it represents the underlining idea.

```py
class CC:
    index = [None for i in range(100)]
    
    def add_element(self, key, val):
        hash_ = abs(hash(key))
        i_ = hash_ %100
       # it does not check if the index is full, in that case it will
       # be an infinite loop
        while(self.index[i_] !=None):
            if(self.index[i_][0] == key):
                self.index[i_][1].append(val)
                return
            i_ += 1
            
        self.index[i_] = [key, [val]]
        
    def get_cc(self):
        return [i for i in self.index if i is not None]
```

```
c = CC()

print(c.get_cc())

>>> []

c.add_element('Sam', 100)
c.add_element('Sam', 120)
c.add_element('Sam', 110)

c.add_element('Andrew', 80)

print(c.get_cc())

>>> [['Andrew', [80]], ['Sam', [100, 120, 110]]]
```